# 2D matrix implementation

Tags: java, matrix, implementation

Each entity in my game has a `Tag` object, and there needs to be a way to **Add** and **Remove** `collisions` between `Tag`'s.

This is my code:

```
public final class CollisionMatrix {

    // TODO: Longs have at most 64 bits, so the current implementation fails
    // when there are more than 64 tags.
    private Map<Integer, Long> matrix = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();

    public CollisionMatrix add(Tag tag1, Tag tag2) {
        int id1 = tag1.id;
        int id2 = tag2.id;
        matrix.put(id1, matrix.getOrDefault(id1, 0L) | (1 << id2));
        matrix.put(id2, matrix.getOrDefault(id2, 0L) | (1 << id1));
        return this;
    }

    public CollisionMatrix remove(Tag tag1, Tag tag2) {
        int id1 = tag1.id;
        int id2 = tag2.id;
        matrix.put(id1, matrix.getOrDefault(id1, 0L) & ~(1 << id2));
        matrix.put(id2, matrix.getOrDefault(id2, 0L) & ~(1 << id1));    
        return this;
    }

    public boolean collidesWith(Tag tag1, Tag tag2) {
        return 0 != (matrix.getOrDefault(tag1.id, 0L) & (1 << tag2.id));
    }

}
```

This is a very ugly implementation of what I'm trying to achieve. But it working (If the number of tags are no more than 64).

**I'm looking for a solution that needs to be efficient and not anti-pattern.**

Answer (score 1):

`Tag` could have a list of tags that indicate collision:

```
   public void add(Tag tag1, Tag tag2) {
        tag1.collisions.Add(tag2);
        tag2.collisions.Add(tag1);
    }

    public void remove(Tag tag1, Tag tag2) {
      if (collidesWith(tag1,tag2)) {
        tag1.collisions.remove(tag2);
        tag2.collisions.remove(tag1);
      }  
    }

    public boolean collidesWith(Tag tag1, Tag tag2) {
        if (tag1.collisions.Contains(tag2) && tag2.collisions.Contains(tag1)) {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't support multiple collision, that is, have a tag collide with others.

Comment: Consider making `Tag.collisions` a `Set<Tag>` instead of a `List<Tag>`.  This will avoid duplicates when adding, and makes `collidesWith()` constant time complexity (as opposed to `List<Tag>` which would be O(tag.collisions.size)).  Also, when removing no need to check if there is a collision - just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, is it just me or are bitwise operators very illegible? Actually I never used them and haven't really seen them either.

To the topic: What about a simple two-dimensional symmetrical array that stores booleans? array[x][y] represents whether or not x collides with y (those could be IDs of two objects assuming they are not random and start from 0).

Somehow I have a feeling that you're trying too hard to be smart there. I'd never come with an idea to represent an array of booleans as a long and I assume that's what you are trying to there.

Comment: If I do an array, then if the number of tags increase, what will I do? Arrays have fixed sizes.

Comment: How is your approach any different from mine then it comes to that? You're making an array where one dimension is 64. One solution would be to create quite big initial array and rewrite if needed or use some nested collections like ArrayList of ArrayLists

Comment: That's why I asked the question, to see if there's a better alternative that does not have those limitations.

Comment: @AfonsoMatos how many tags do you expect there to be? Using a simple two-dimensional array of booleans with fixed size of 1000x1000 or something is probably still the most efficient solution. Or you could keep track of how many tags you have (there shouldn't be new added in runtime) and use that number to initialize the array.